# What is the efficiency of a query + subquery that finds the minimum parameter of a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, performance

I'm currently taking an SQL course and trying to understand efficiency of queries.

Given this query, what's the efficiency of it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Age = (SELECT MIN(Age)
             FROM Customers)
```

What i'm trying to understand is if the subquery runs once at the beginning and then the query is O(n+n)?
Or does the subquery run everytime you go through a customer's age which makes it O(n^2)?
Thank you!

Comment: SQL is declarative, you only tell *what* you want **not** how to get it. The DBMS will figure out a way how to get it itself. And that way, the DBMS figures out, depends on a lot of things and can even vary depending on the actual data that is currently in the tables. So there is no answer to your question. You'd need to look at the execution plan your DBMS generates for the query and get *its* run time complexity. But as I said that's **not** the complexity of the query.

Comment: @stickybit is there any chance I can contact you privatly to ask another question about something related to this?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand *how* the query optimizer interperets a query you have to review the *execution / explain* plan which almost every RDBMS makes available.

As noted in the comments you tell the RDBMS what you *want*, not *how* to get it.

Very often it helps to have a deeper understanding of the particular database engine being used in order to write a query in the most performant way, ie, to be able to *think* like the query processor.

Like any language, there's more than one way to skin a cat, so to speak, and with SQL there is usually more than one way to write a query that results in the same output - very often many ways, depending on the complexity.

*How* a query execution plan gets built and executed is determined by the query optimizer at compile time and depends on many factors, depending on the RDBMS, such as data cardinality, table size, row size, estimated number of rows, sargability, indexes, available resources, current load, concurrency, isolation level - just to name a few.

It often helps to write queries in the most performant way by thinking what *you* would have to do to accomplish the same task.

In your example, you are looking for all the rows in a table where a particular value equals another value. You have chosen to find that value by first looking for the minimum age - you would only have to do this once as it's a single scalar value, so it's reasonable to assume (but not guaranteed) the database engine would do the same.

You could also approach the problem by aggregating and limiting to the top qualifying row and including ties, if the syntax is supported by the RDBMS, and joining the results.

Ultimately there is no black and white answer.