# Efficiency of ORDER BY DESC & LIMIT Vs. WHERE & Subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-order-by, where-clause, limit

Assume that I want to present the details of the most expensive product from a table of products.

I consider 2 ways of doing it:

- The first way is to use `ORDER BY DESC` and `LIMIT 1`.
- The second way is to use the WHERE clause as follows:
  `WHERE price = (subquery that uses aggregate function MAX)`.

Which of the ways is more efficient? I will be glad to read your explanations.

Note that the SELECT in both of the queries uses * (to present all the details).

I assume that the first way is more efficient, but I would like to be sure it's correct and know why it is or isn't.

This is written in [SQLBolt](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/filtering_sorting_query_results) about LIMIT & OFFSET:

> Another clause which is commonly used with the ORDER BY clause are the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses, which are a useful optimization to indicate to the database the subset of the results you care about.
> The LIMIT will reduce the number of rows to return, and the optional OFFSET will specify where to begin counting the number rows from.

> .... Using these clauses, the database can then execute queries **faster** and more **efficiently** by processing and returning only the requested content.

Thank you very much beforehand.

Comment: You would need to run both queries and look at the query execution plans or both. You might find the query optimiser converts both to the same underlying query

Comment: The answer might depend on a) your particular SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.), and b) your table data.  Best bet is to run `EXPLAIN` on both queries and see for yourself.  The `LIMIT` version looks faster to me as it avoids an extra table scan.

Comment: @NickW thanks for replying. So you are claiming both of the ways might result in same efficiency?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for replying. Actually, I have never used `EXPLAIN` before. Do you have example for my case?

Comment: They might do. As the other commentator said, it’s dependent on multiple variables: DBMS, data volume, indexes, hardware, etc

Comment: @NickW  The assumption is that my table data doesn't contain a lot of information, and the particular SQL database might be MySQL, just for example.

Comment: Ok, but you telling me this information doesn’t help in anyway to determine which query is more efficient - if that’s why you supplied it? The only way to determine it, as has been stated previously, is for you to run EXPLAIN on the 2 queries on your platform with your data

Comment: Very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70471771/15332650)

Comment: Isn't it should be simpler? I thought that the sub-query makes the whole thing be more complex, and therefore result in less efficiency.

Comment: You need to bear in mind that the query that you write is not necessarily the query that is run. Every DBMS has a query optimiser that takes the sql query you’ve written and determines the optimal way to retrieve the results - which may result in a significant query re-write

Comment: @NickW I updated the post. Can't I trust the updated information too?

Comment: What makes you think you can’t trust this information and I’m also not sure what you mean by “too” - what else can’t you trust and why?